# How to switch from unity to gnome

Tags: unity, gnome

Default ui for Ubuntu 14.04 being Unity, want to switch to Gnome.

Can't find usual way to switch at login screen as mentioned here.

http://www.techienote.com/2011/03/switching-to-gnome-in-ubuntu-11-04.html

Comment: Why not downloading Ubuntu GNOME remix? BTW, are you aware that that link is from 2011 and about 11.04?

Comment: In my experience, the most reliable installer is ubuntu desktop, so I will generally start there if a machine is giving me problems making everything work.

Comment: Have you thought about simply installing Ubuntu Gnome? http://ubuntugnome.org/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Step 1 :** To get started, press **Ctrl + Alt + T** on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below to enable Gnome session

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

**Step 2 :** Restart and on the logon screen, **click** the **option** to change your session.
[image]

**Step 3 :** Then choose **GNOME Flashback (Metacity)**
[image]

Enjoy your Desktop
[image]

Source : [How to switch to GNOME Desktop Environment in Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr](http://www.techienote.com/2014/04/how-to-switch-to-gnome-desktop-environment-in-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr.html)

Comment: There are a few glitches in Metacity at the moment though, so you might want to run Compiz.

Comment: As of this date I'm finding Metacity to be fine.

Answer (score 4):

The document you refer to, is many years old. In modern versions of Ubuntu, there is a small button next to your user name. When you click it, you get a list of sessions to choose from.

However, there seems to be a small bug in 14.04 that prevents that list from being shown sometimes. If you select another user and then back to your own user again, it works. I'll update this with a link to the bug report when I've filed on. I just noticed this myself so I haven't had the time yet.

EDIT: I filed it here; https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-greeter/+bug/1309846

If you have something to add, do it there. If you're annoyed by this bug, click on "This bug affects me" in order to bring the heat up.

Comment: I have not observed this behavior. As a changed I have installed gnome-session-fallback package.