# unity fails to start after booting

Tags: 14.04, unity

I am using UBUNTU 14.04.2 on my lenovo E531 laptop.My problem is:  after booting the computer,graphical interface of ubuntu fails to start and it shows a black screen. I'd consider myself a beginner, but I know how to use terminal commands on the TTY screen a little bit.
I appreciate any help/guidance in advance.

Update:
i have tried lots of different methods but the result is :failure :-( 
i installed gnome shell :
 http://itsfoss.com/how-to-install-gnome-in-ubuntu-14-04/ 
 but at the end the black screen is all i have 
i also tried this method :
[Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver)
but the result was not helpful again

my Nvidia driver is Nvidia-331, and it was working fine before this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with opening a terminal and checking the output of:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

If everything shows yes, your graphic card shouldn't have a problem with unity. If not, you'll have to switch something your graphic card supports, [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450294/how-to-switch-from-unity-to-gnome) is an alternative to unity.

Given that the problem isn't your graphic card and you havn't installed any new graphic drivers prior to this error I would suggest to reinstall unity.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: I would not suggest the gnome would solve a problem with the graphics card or the gnome would be any better then Unity. Both make heavy use of 3d graphics . I would suggest K/X/L ubuntu >> gnome-shell . In addition, how would re-installing unity solve anything ?

Comment: Well, the question is regarding that Unity fails to start. Testing to reinstall and check if it makes any difference feels like the first step in most problems of this type?

Comment: Perhaps with windows, but not with linux. These problems are most likely due to hardware problems or a misconfigured use setting. reinstalling does not solve either . User settings in $HOME need to be reset or deleted manually. You can usually delete them and they will be autogenerated. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Comment: gnome (unity and gnome-shell) are the most demanding on graphics cards as I said earlier. If these interfaces are slow, try an alternate desktop.

Comment: Thank you dear Niklas fot your help, i tried your method but it didn't work. "sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging" something is wrong with this command:
"PPA to be removed unity-team staging
Warning: Could not find package list for PPA: unity-team staging"

Comment: Thank you Bodhi Zazen , i tried to reset my unity configuration ans you suggested but after prompting >>unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity .

the respond is:
(unity-tweak-tool:2644) failed to commit changes to dconf: cannot auto launch D-Bus without x11 $Display

Comment: I tried lots of different methods over the last month however none of them worked! The only solution that was helpful, was reinstalling Ubuntu :   http://askubuntu.com/questions/613469/is-it-possible-to-remove-and-reinstall-ubuntu-without-affecting-windows