# Switching from Unity to Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome

I no longer want Unity, and I want to switch to Gnome, I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/452175/364819) that you have to install `gnome-session-fallback` package.

To do this, however, when running:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

I've got this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnome-session-fallback is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  gnome-session-flashback

E: Package 'gnome-session-fallback' has no installation candidate
```

So does this mean that I should install `gnome-session-flashback` instead of `gnome-session-fallback` to get Gnome? Also as I want to get the latest version of Gnome, which would be Gnome 3 and not 2, is this the correct package to install?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gnome-session-fallback` is not available anymore for Ubuntu >14.04 , so in order to get that old gnome you should refer to the other package which is called flashback.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

indeed gnome-flashback is exactly the same as gnome-fallback.

Quoted from [Gnome wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeFlashback?action=show&redirect=GnomeFlashback):

> Gnome Flashback is a session for Gnome 3 which was initially called
>   "Gnome Fallback", and shipped as a stand-alone session in Debian and
>   Ubuntu. It provides a similar user experience to the Gnome 2.x series
>   sessions. The differences to the Mate project is that Gnome Flashback
>   uses Gtk+3 and tries to follow the current Gnome development by
>   integrating recent changes of the Gnome libraries. The development
>   currently lags behind a little but a lot of progress has been made and
>   most importantly many open bugs have been fixed.
>
> Currently Gnome Flashback consists of the following components:
>
> - GnomePanel: This component provides a a flexible panel. One or more    of these panels can be added to the screen and can be populated with
>     multiple applets to open application, indicators for sound and
>     network, a clock applet with date, time and weather and many more.
> - Metacity: The window manager of Gnome Flashback, optionally other    window managers such as mutter can be used but Metacity is the one
>     thats officially supported. Recently Metacity has been ported to
>     GTK+3 and gained the side-by-side window tiling feature that is also
>     available in Gnome Shell.
> - GnomeApplets: This component provides a collection of useful applets    for the Gnome Panel.
> - Flashback module: A new module since September 2014. It provides    session files, background features, a sound applet and shutdown
>     dialogs.
> - Notification Daemon: This is now part of Gnome Flashback and will be    part of the next release.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my question slightly to get a little more out of it and not have to ask a new question. Could you please edit your answer just to quickly answer the final question I added. :)

Comment: This still answers you. Read the quote from the gnome wiki

Comment: @ParanoidPanda  No, gnome-flashback does not provide the latest version of the Gnome desktop enviroment. It is a gnome 3 session that tries to maintain the spirit of gnome 2.

Answer (score 3):

As you don't actually specify that you wish to install Gnome 2.X (which is what gnome-session-flashback installs).

If you wish to use the latest version of Gnome in the 3.X series, you can install **ubuntu-gnome-desktop**.