# Switching from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu gnome 16.04

Tags: unity, gnome

From what I understand, Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 are 2 different OS.

My question is, is it possible to convert my installation of Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04? Or maybe I got it all wrong and gnome is just a desktop environment that I can switch to from unity? Maybe?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Apparently the forum found a possible duplicate so lemme clear that up :). I am not asking what the differences between Unity and Gnome DE are, I'm asking about the entire OS flavors if I can convert one to the other without a complete reinstall.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/189912/how-to-install-the-gnome-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-14.04/

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question, That question was about switching to gnome classic and it is gnome shell

Comment: The second answer of the aforementioned question deals with the installation of GNOME 3: http://askubuntu.com/a/650966/271 Is there anything else that you need to know which is not addressed by that?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto One thing is very different. OP here wants to Convert, not install another DE `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. Yes, it's possible, but that's not pure Ubuntu Gnome 3. Many things will unity + mix up of settings here and there.

Comment: @Anwar your answer here is clearly better than those on the other Q, however they are still duplicate. One solution would be to reopen this A and flag the other one as duplicate.

Comment: From this of OP "maybe I got it all wrong and gnome is just a desktop environment that I can switch to from unity?" It can be assumed that OP knows about installing another DE on top a one and switch to it. But he asking if he can entirely change the Distro (with DE) without re-installing. There are slight differences.

Answer (score 6):

One way to switch to a Ubuntu gnome is installing `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` metapackage. But, that you give you two DEs aren't much pure. Unity settings sometimes causes problem in Gnome-Shell and vice versa.

To completely remove all components of Ubuntu and install Ubuntu-gnome instead, I suggest using this script. The script was developed by the person who was providing the command for these kinds of Switching till 15.04.

- Download the `purebuntu.py` file from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/aysiu/purebuntu).
- Install the `apt-rdepends` package using the terminal command

  ```
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apt-rdepends
  ```
- Run the `purebuntu.py` file using this syntax:

  ```
  python purebuntu.py --remove ubuntu-desktop --keep ubuntu-gnome-desktop
  ```
- This will generate an `apt-get` command which will remove Ubuntu related packages and install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` metapackage.

This will give you a fairly clean Ubuntu gnome desktop. Take note though, You might lost already installed extra packages because of this operation.

P.S.: You can generate the commands to switch back using:

```
    python purebuntu.py --keep ubuntu-desktop --remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: Is it safe? It would be great if you add some procedure for roll back in your answer or [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/853482/switching-from-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-to-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @Rahul Safe in which term? It is better when you don't want to re-install. However, it can remove all other custom installed packages as I said in the answer. Though you can always save package names as a backup and re-install those packages if failed.

Comment: @Rahul I've edited text including the commands to rollback