# Switching from Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome

I recently switched from 16.04 to Gnome version and I wanna roll back, is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/813752/switching-from-ubuntu-16-04-to-ubuntu-gnome-16-04/813828#813828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

### Start in text-only mode

- Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, which will bring up the Grub menu.
- Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.
- Select the line ending with `(recovery mode)`
- Press <kbd>Return</kbd> and your machine will begin the boot process.
- After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including `Drop to root shell prompt`. Press <kbd>Return</kbd> with this option highlighted.
- The PC will start in a terminal.

### Run these commands:

Mount partitions in read-write mode

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
```

Update repositories

```
apt-get update
```

Install `aptitude` and `deborphan`

```
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of `gnome` that are not necessary in Ubuntu

```
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
```

Reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Eliminate orphan packages

```
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Remove downloaded packages

```
apt-get clean
```

Restart system

```
reboot
```

Comment: When you say, "try this", are you not sure if this procedure will work? To me it looks like it should.

Comment: @wjandrea: I have worked with Lubuntu - Unity - Kubuntu.. But Murphy's law: Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong.