# Convert Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I have used Ubuntu Gnome since 14.04 and have Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 installed on a machine that I use daily for work. recently, I have been using my wife's laptop which has Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity on it and have to come to the conclusion that I like Unity better than Gnome. My question is this, I want to have Unity on my desktop and remove Gnome but I'm guessing as Ubuntu Gnome is a distro that it isn't as simple as just removing gnome and installing Unity. I have a lot software installed and I don't what to reinstall everything again. Is there an easy and reliable way to convert my installation to vanilla 16.04 and keep all my software and settings?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe running `taskel`, I tried this in ubuntu server (from XFCE to Unity) and I haven´t any problem. First try this with a virtual machine (I prefer `virtualbox`)

Comment: See at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/853482/switching-from-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-to-ubuntu-16-04