# Tracking down a random freeze?

Tags: hard-drive, google-chrome, freeze

Since updating to 15.10 on my Thinkpad T420, I've experienced random freezes periodically. Usually within an hour of using the laptop. It ran just fine on 15.04. I've tried looking at /var/log/syslog but I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for. There's obviously lots of errors and warnings that *seem* less significant.

When it freezes, I can't switch to tty1, can't do REISUB, and usually the cursor doesn't move (although 10 minutes ago, while in Chrome, the page I had open stopped responding, I refreshed, and while it was refreshing the page, icons and such in and outside of Chrome gradually stopped responding one at a time). Not unlike when I've had a HDD failure in the past. I have a Samsung 830 SSD on that note.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same setup, X220 with Samsung 840 EVO and the same type of random freeze.

It seems that the actual problem is somewhere within the graphical subsystem and affects Compiz users on Intel graphics cards. See this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1511819

As a workaround you may try to switch to Gnome running on Metacity, as described in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/452175/168315.