# Ubuntu Desktop Environment Help

Tags: unity, gnome

I have bought and install Ubuntu 15.10 installer disc from a local software store. After installing Ubuntu , it comes up with "Gnome" desktop environment. I'm just a newer to Ubuntu and other linux platforms.
I want to know "How can I change Gnome Desktop to Unity Desktop & how to switch between them easily". Every steps I want to know to do so.
Thanks , askUbuntu Team.

Comment: Hope this helps you:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/450294/how-to-switch-from-unity-to-gnome

Comment: You *bought* the installer disc? I hope you did not pay too much for it... Ubuntu is free open source software. You can download it legally for nothing (or a donation).

Comment: Yes, I bought the installer disc because our ISP's network speed is slow and not reliable. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Ubuntu Unity desktop environment alongside GNOME desktop environment.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Log out - on login screen select **Unity** - log back in.
To change back to GNOME desktop environment :
Log out - on login screen select GNOME and log in.

Personal note :

After installation of Unity has finished, I recommend to perform a reboot of the Ubuntu system.