# GNOME theme on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and the new default GNOME theme is not installed.

Is there an option to be set?

I ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && do-release-upgrade
```

My system still has the old unity theme, and I want the new one.

---

Solved

After the installation you should be able to select the GNOME desktop on the login screen.

ref: [How to switch from unity to gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450294/how-to-switch-from-unity-to-gnome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install it with:

```
apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: i have a vm here with the same ubuntu version, after a run this command  the unity theme still the same, even after restarting. there is any further step to take ?

Comment: You can choose your desktop manager gnome/unity on login screen
https://askubuntu.com/questions/450294/how-to-switch-from-unity-to-gnome